# Array.join("<br>") method not printing each element of an array as a string on a separate line

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, math

I'm stuck on this. Please guide me on this Javascript code.

I'm trying to print the names of each month on a separate line. The code I'm using is given below.

```
const printArray = (arr) => {
console.log( arr.join( "<br>" ) );
};
const months = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ];
printArray( months );
```

Now, this should come up with printing each element of the array or name of each month in a separate line but it's printing each element next to each other in the console.

"Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec"

whereas I want each element to be printed in a separate line as given below,

```
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec
```

Please, tell me why is that happening and also tell me the fix to it!

Comment: The console does not use HTML markup

Comment: Use `\n` instead of `<br>`. The console uses normal white space characters, not HTML.